# laravel running in production on machine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I cannot get laravel to run locally.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

'prod' => array('dossiya-v2'),
'local' => array('ubuntu', 'localhost')
));
```

and I used

```
php -S localhost:4000
```

To start my php server. I keep getting the error: 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.' unless i change the above code to:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(
  function(){ return 'local' ; }
);
```

How can I change it such that I don't have to put in that code?

Comment: have you run `hostname` in your terminal to see what the local hostname is?

Comment: @chrisG I get: `Mohameds-MacBook-Pro.local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add whatever comes back from the terminal when you run

```
hostname
```

This will likely be something like `Your-computer-name.local`

So you would add that to your array like this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'prod' => array('dossiya-v2'),
    'local' => array('ubuntu', 'Your-computer-name.local')
));
```

See here in the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration